# Angular $scope.$watch is not triggered when i assign $scope to another variable and change the watched value on new variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, watch

I have an array and a watcher in my `$scope`. Watcher detects changes on the array property. Watcher works as expected: triggers listener when i update array contents.

When I assign my `$scope` to some other variable (`var newScope = $scope`), however,
and then push an item to `newScope`'s array , the watcher is not called.

Javascript should assign $scope to newScope by reference right? So, `$scope` and `newScope` will refer to the same object in memory. Then, why watcher is not called when I modify array on `newScope`?

Comment: Can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

If you assign `$scope` to `newScope` then watching `$scope` won't do anything unless you update `$scope`. The reference is no longer `$scope` you want to be watching `newScope`

Comment: Javascript should assign $scope to newScope by reference right? So, $scope and newScope will refer to the same object in memory. Isn't that right?

Comment: They both exist in memory yes, but still as their own variables. So calling newScope doesn't refer to $scope even though it has all it's properties & methods. For example, if you were to use an angular method like location (i'm fairly certain location updates in scope), It won't modify `newScope` it will modify $scope because that is the original object that angular works with.